# how to recognize the Gaussian distribtuion in a formula?

Tags: normal-distribution, gaussian-process

For someone is the question quite easy but I would like to know how to detect in a formula the Gaussian distribution? For instance in the equation in attached picture, what are the keys to say there is a Gaussian

[image]

the picture was taken from the http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW2.pdf

best regards!

Comment: Maybe it would be helpful to distinguish the following: are you wondering *why* the posterior is a Gaussian distribution or are you wondering about *how* they figured that out? Your question is a bit confusing concerning that point... for example: why is it Gaussian? It’s density has a description that we call Gaussian... it is that simple...

Comment: @malocho See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Density_function ... the denominator there is just a scaling constant to make it integrate to 1. You can equate terms one by one in your picture with the terms in the equation for the joint density at the Wikipedia link.

Comment: @FabianWerner if I would give you a formula, how could you recognize that that formula is a Gaussian?

Comment: As I said: if some function in x is a density and (up to a constant) it is equal to $\exp((-1/2)[x-x_0]^t(\text{symmetric matrix})[x-x_0])$ then we say (this is a definition) that this is a Gaussian density/random variable. Is the question about the constant, I.e. are you confused that the $1/\sqrt{2\pi^d}$ in front is missing?

Comment: no not because of the missing of a constant term...

but your sentence " is equal to exp((−1/2)[−0](symmetric matrix)[−0]) then we say (this is a definition) that this is a Gaussian density/random variable" answers my question